# Merge 'with' and 'whereHas' in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have this code in Laravel 5, using Eloquent, which is working perfectly:

```
$filterTask = function($query) use ($id) {
    $query->where('taskid', $id);
};

User::whereHas('submissions', $filterTask)->with(['submissions' => $filterTask])->get();
```

Basically the goal is to get only those users with their filtered submissions, which has any of them.
However, it seems wasting to run both **whereHas** and **with** methods with the same callback function. Is there a way to simplify it?

Thanks.

Comment: No, there's no other way (using eloquent relation queries ofc). Why would it be wasting?

Comment: Well, since we are filtering the submissions with the condition twice; I just hoped there is a solution to make it one query instead of more, but @lukasgeiter made it totally clear.

Comment: Why does this answer has too few votes?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In terms of performance you can't really optimize anything here (except if you were to move from eloquent relations to joins). With or without `whereHas`, two queries will be run. One to select all users another one to load the related models. When you add the `whereHas` condition a subquery is added, but it's still two queries.

However, syntactically you could optimize this a bit by adding a [query scope](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#query-scopes) to your model (or even a base model if you want to use this more often):

```
public function scopeWithAndWhereHas($query, $relation, $constraint){
    return $query->whereHas($relation, $constraint)
                 ->with([$relation => $constraint]);
}
```

Usage:

```
User::withAndWhereHas('submissions', function($query) use ($id){
    $query->where('taskid', $id);
})->get();
```

Comment: I'd probably rename it too `withHas` for readability

Comment: I added it in a trait which I can easily use in all models I want to. Very recommended!

Answer (score 5):

The '**macroable**' way (**Laravel 5.4+**)

Add this inside a service provider's `boot()` method.

```
\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder\Eloquent::macro('withAndWhereHas', function($relation, $constraint){
    return $this->whereHas($relation, $constraint)->with([$relation => $constraint]);
});
```

Comment: In Laravel 5.8 I had to do:

\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::macro('withAndWhereHas', function($relation, $constraint){
            return $this->whereHas($relation, $constraint)->with([$relation => $constraint]);
        });

Answer (score 2):

You can now achieve that In Laravel 9.17

Example:

```
use App\Models\User;

$users = User::withWhereHas('posts', function ($query) {
  $query->where('featured', true);
})->get();
```

Check out the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads-with-relationship-existence) for more information

Answer (score 0):

I want to extend the answer from @lukasgeiter using static functions.

```
public static function withAndWhereHas($relation, $constraint){
    return (new static)->whereHas($relation, $constraint)
        ->with([$relation => $constraint]);
}
```

Usage is the same

```
User::withAndWhereHas('submissions', function($query) use ($id){
    $query->where('taskid', $id);
})->get();
```

Comment: But in this case you can't mix it with other queries. This should be the first function that you have to call statically from the model and that won't always be the case.