# With method and pivot table Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

Here is how I get project and groups:

```
$groups = Group::with('projects')->get();
```

In my `project_group` pivot table have `admin_id` field and I need to check that field and for example take only projects and groups `where admin_id = 1`, so I need to take all projects group where filed in pivot table equals 1.

This is in my Group model:

```
public function projects(){
        return $this ->belongsToMany('App\Project','project_group')->withPivot('admin_id');
        }
```

Here is example for 1 group, but don't know how to take for all groups:

`Group::find(1)->proejcts()->where('admin_id', '=',1)->get();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you only projects with `admin_id = 1`

```
$groups = Group::with(['projects' => function($q){
    $q->where('admin_id', 1);
}])->get();
```

If you want only groups with `admin_id = 1` as well you need to add a `whereHas` condition:

```
$adminIdCondition = function($q){
    $q->where('admin_id', 1);
};

$groups = Group::with(['projects' => $adminIdCondition])
               ->whereHas('projects', $adminIdCondition)
               ->get();;
```

For a somewhat nicer syntax for the second case, take a look at [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29594039/1903366)

Comment: Thanks! Could you tell me what this do: $adminIdCondition = function($q){
    $q->where('admin_id', 1);
};

Comment: It stores the closure from the first code example in a variable because it has to be passed to `with()` as well as `whereHas()`. This way you avoid having the exact same function twice in your code.

Comment: Which result I get in $adminIdCondition variable?

Comment: No result. It's a temporary variable to store the filter function.

Comment: Aha it just return `where` closure?