# Laravel - is there a way to combine whereHas and with

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm currently facing a small problem. I want to return a model only if a relation with certain conditions exists. That's working fine with the whereHas()-method.

```
$m = Model
    ::whereHas(
        'programs',
        function($q) {
            $q->active();
        }
    );
```

However, calling the relation as a property like this will give me all (not filtered results).

```
$m->programs;
```

So basically what I'm doing now is this:

```
$m = Model
    ::whereHas(
        'programs',
        function($q) {
            $q->active();
        }
    )
    ->with(array('programs' => function($q) {
        $q->active();
    }))
;
```

That's working fine but I feel very bad about doing the same thing again. That can't be the right way. How can I achieve this without kind of duplicating the code?

Comment: I don't think there is a shorter/nicer way with query builder.

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591931/merge-with-and-wherehas-in-laravel-5#answer-29594039

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a concept of an "active program" is important in your application, consider creating a separate relation just for active programs (in this case I'm presuming you have a HasMany relation):

```
class Model
{
    public function activePrograms()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Program::class)->active();
    }
}
```

Then you can simplify your query to:

```
Model::with('activePrograms')->has('activePrograms')->get();
```

Comment: interesting! you can add a query builder modified to a relation? it's different classes, I didn't know they are compatible

Comment: Yes, you can chain any builder method on the relationship. It's one of Eloquent's most powerful features in my opinion.

Comment: I thought about this and then decided 'nay, that would be too cool' ;)) thanks for the info

Comment: This indeed is interesting. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 9.17 `withWhereHas`

Example:

```
   $a= Model::withWhereHas('programs', function ($query) {
      $query->active();
    })->get();
```

Check out the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads-with-relationship-existence) for more information.