# How to use '::whereHas()' as a constraint for '::with()' query when using Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a query:

```
Posts::whereHas('comments', function($query){
          $query->where('name', 'like', 'asd');
      })->with('comments')->get();
```

It returns all posts that have comments which have name like 'asd' with all comments of these posts. Can I use the above constraint in '::whereHas' for the 'with' method, so it would not return all comments, but only those that match the requirements? Or do I have to duplicate the query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create query something like this, almost without duplicate :)

```
$callback = function($query) {
     $query->where('name', 'like', 'asd');
}
Posts::whereHas('comments', $callback)->with(['comments' => $callback])->get();
```

Or, you can make like in this post [Laravel - is there a way to combine whereHas and with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711549/laravel-is-there-a-way-to-combine-wherehas-and-with)

Comment: unfortunately that all fails, when you have nested `whereHas` query