# Laravel eager loading & whereHas

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Several questions have been asked about this but none provided a satisfactory explanation for this problem.

I run the following query:

```
$return = Vacation::whereHas('dates', function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
    $query->whereBetween('start_date', [$from, $to]);
})->get();
```

According to the query log, this produces the following SQL. The returned result is correct but there is a problem with the JOINed data.

```
select * from `vacations` where exists (select * from `vacation_dates` where `vacations`.`id` = `vacation_dates`.`vacation_id` and `start_date` between '2017-08-01 00:00:00' and '2017-08-30 00:00:00')
```

Since there's no JOIN, the related records are added afterwards through eager loading and the constraint is lost.

The scenario involves `Vacations` that have multiple start / stop dates and I want to check which Vacations have a `start_date` within the `$start` and `$end` date range.

If there's no occurrences, no records are returned.

When there is an occurrence, the Vacation is returned with ALL the dates and not just the ones in the constraint.

I understand how / what it's doing but don't see how I can get what I need: the record with the joined data that follows the constraint.

Anyone?

Comment: have you tried whereRaw() instead ?

Comment: Yes, doesn't seem to do what I want either.

Answer (score 9):

Solution:

```
$callback = function($query) use($from, $to) {
            $query->whereBetween('start_date', [$from, $to]);
        };
        $return = Vacation::whereHas('dates', $callback)->with(['dates' => $callback])->get();
```

[Solution is from this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34739349/149664)

Answer (score 5):

Same answer as @stef gave, but better looking syntax (I believe)

```
$return = Vacation::query()
    ->whereHas('dates', $datesFilter = function($query) use ($from, $to) {
        $query->whereBetween('start_date', [$from, $to]);
    })
    ->with(['dates' => $datesFilter])
    ->get();
```

Comment: What's "query()" for?

Comment: @RobbyAlvianJayaMulia that is the syntax to explicitly show that you are starting a (db) query. It returns you an instance of Eloquent\Builder class, so you can autocomplete further methods.
When you use `Vacation::whereHas()`, it returns the same Builder class implicitly