# Laravel whereHas getting the relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm doing a Laravel application to manage events. An Attendant and and Event have a belongsToMany relationship. An attendant has multiple events and viceversa.
The pivot column has an extra field called `uuid`, this is like the ticket id to the event. 
I need to validate the entrance of an Attendant to an Event. So the Attendant scans a QR code with the `uuid` of the pivot table.

So I have this function

```
public function validateTicket(Request $request, $ticket) {
    $event = Event::fromTicket($ticket);
    \Log::info($event);
    return new EventResource($event);
}
```

And the static method `fromTicket` is:

```
public static function fromTicket($ticket) {
    return static::whereHas('attendants', function($q) use ($ticket) {
        $q->where('uuid', $ticket);
    })->first();
}
```

The problem is that I need the relationship too, this because I need to register the hour of entrance of an Attendant, and this entrance could happen many times.

Is there a way to return the relationship too during the `whereHas` query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34739097/how-to-use-wherehas-as-a-constraint-for-with-query-when-using-eloque/34739349#34739349 might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No because it needs the original models relationship to get the pivot table, fear not there is a solution that is very close to the original. Instead include all attendants and do a condition in the include and only the attendent you need will be present.

```
public static function fromTicket($ticket) {
    return static::whereHas('attendants',
        function($query) use ($ticket) {
            $query->where('uuid', $ticket);
        })->with(['attendants' => function ($query) use ($ticket) {
            $query->where('uuid', $ticket);
        }])->first();
}
```

This will include the attendants, but only the one with the correct ticket, so now you can do `$event->attendants->first()`, this is two queries still quite optimized but not optimal, my easiest solution for how you portrayed your problem.

Comment: This works perfect, I was thinking about this as the solution, but I'm still, wonder if there is a more optimal solution. Thanks for you answer, I'm using it and worked well for my problem

Comment: I do not know about it, thou this is all still done in one query and will call it 99% optimised. Thats the sacrifice we have to take working with an orm