# Laravel Eloquent Relationships findMany or find

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

If you have two models Post and Comment, and in the Comment model you have defined a belongsTo(), relationship called posts, I know that it is possible to do this:

```
App\Comment::find(1)->posts()->where('category', 3)->get()
```

But what I want is to pass more than one primary key id to the method find like:

```
App\Comment::find([1,2,3])->posts()->where('category', 3)->get()
```

Or

```
App\Comment::findMany([1,2,3])->posts()->where('category', 3)->get()
```

These two gives me the error `method posts does not exist`. So how else can I handle this problem?

Comment: I finally found the best way to do this from [@Lukasgeiter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29594039/4128530) He uses a combination of with and whereHas in the query.

Comment: I am using a more complex query than my example, your answers did not work for me when used alone so I decided to use a combination of both with and whereHas. Your answers helped me though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me [@Lukasgeiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591931/merge-with-and-wherehas-in-laravel-5/29594039#29594039) He uses a combination of with and whereHas in the query.

Answer (score 7):

When you're using `find()` method, you get a model, but `findMany()` returns a collection.

What you probably want is this:

```
App\Comment::whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->with(['posts' => function($q) {
    $q->where('category', 3);
}])->get();
```

Comment: thanks a lot and it's better to use `$q->where('posts.category', 3);` since both tables can have same column

Answer (score -5):

For that you have to use with callback method,like below

```
App\Comment::whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->with(['posts' => function($query) {
     $query->whereCategory(3);
}])->get();
```

Comment: You shouldn't copy&paste others' answers . You copied `$q` instead of `$query` (which is everywhere in the original documentation) and you copied my error from original answer `})->get()` instead of `}])->get()` which I fixed in like a minute after I've posted my original answer.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Something's fishy.