# Laravel whereHas returns unexpected results

Tags: php, laravel

My Query:

```
Description::whereHas('expenses', function($query) {
        $query->where('date', $this->date);
    })->with('expenses')->get();
```

The above query returns all descriptions for the given date, but it returns ALL expenses for that description, instead of the expenses for the given date. I fail to understand why this is and I would like to understand this first and foremost. Is this because of the `with('expenses')` I am just eager loading all expenses for each description? And with the whereHas I just return all descriptions that have at least one expense for the given date?

If all of the above is true, how can I return all descriptions for the given date including the expenses for the given date?

Description Model:

```
public function expenses()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Expense::class);
}
```

Expense Model:

```
public function description()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Description::class);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge 'with' and 'whereHas' in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591931/merge-with-and-wherehas-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only filtering which `Description` objects should be loaded. You should apply the same filter to the eager loading so only these are added to the model.

```
Description::whereHas('expenses', function($query) {
        $query->where('date', $this->date);
    })
    ->with([
        'expenses' => function($query) {
            $query->where('date', $this->date);
        }
    ])
    ->get();
```