# Laravel Eloquents: Check if child relationship has no data, Dont return any data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three entities `Inbox , Document , Category`

inbox has relation with document and document has many categories,

I have an Eloquent query that check relation between inbox and document and return inbox with documents data,

The Problem is: 
I want to list all inbox with documents data only if document has no category (if it has one or more categories i dont want list this document with it's inboxes).

So i have this query now, that is not works correctly:

```php
public static function getUserAndJobPositionsInbox($id, $type)
{
       return self::with(['documents' => function($q){

           $q->has('categories', '==', 0);

       }])->where('inboxable_id', $id)
          ->where('inboxable_type', $type)->get();
}
```

This query will return **inbox** data with no documents if the documents has no categories

> BUT i don't want inbox data if documents has no categories. just return empty

The result is :

```php
{
    "data": {
        "user_inbox_documents": null,
        "job_positions_documents": [
            [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "document_id": 3,
                    "document_reference": "RPL2p",
                    "inboxable_id": 3,
                    "inboxable_type": "App\\Models\\JobPosition",
                    "path_id": "2",
                    "created_at": "2018-09-12 13:21:23",
                    "updated_at": "2018-09-12 13:21:23",
                    "documents": []
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "document_id": 3,
                    "document_reference": "RPL2p",
                    "inboxable_id": 2,
                    "inboxable_type": "App\\Models\\JobPosition",
                    "path_id": "1",
                    "created_at": "2018-09-12 13:21:23",
                    "updated_at": "2018-09-12 13:21:23",
                    "documents": []
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your relationships.

Comment: try withCount(['domunets as noCatDocCount' => function($query){ $query->has(..)}])->whereNot('noCatDocCount',0);

Comment: this may helps you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591931/merge-with-and-wherehas-in-laravel-5

Comment: Please check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52295374/5013099

Answer (score 0):

You can check the existence of nested relationships using dot (.) for example following code (Laravel documentation) gets all the posts that have at least one comment and that comment should have atleast one vote.

```
// Retrieve all posts that have at least one comment with votes...
$posts = App\Post::has('comments.votes')->get();
```

**So from above example, you can modify you code as follows:**

```
public static function getUserAndJobPositionsInbox($id, $type)
{
    return self::has('documents.categories')
         ->where('inboxable_id', $id)
         ->where('inboxable_type', $type)->get();
}
```