# Laravel Eloquent "with()" eager loading & "whereHas()" conditions

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-5.7, laravel-collection

I have 2 tables: '**Author**' and '**Book**', with the following straightforward relationship:

```
class Author extends Model
{
    public function books() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Book');
    }
}

class Book extends Model 
{
    public function author() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Author');
    }
}
```

The Book model has an attribute `price` (float) and `category` (string).

I'm trying to find an efficient way to do these 3 things in 1 query:

1. get a list of all the `authors` that have `books` from `category` **comedy**, `created_at` between date1 and date2.
2. **the authors in the list should have an extra attribute** `highest_price`, which is the highest price of all the author's books that match the criteria from step 1.
3. the list of books should be sorted desc by `price`, and the end result list of authors should also be sorted desc on that new attribute `highest_price`.

The result must be like this:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Author ABC'
        highest_price: 15
        books: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'book1',
                category: 'comedy',
                price: 15
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'book2',
                category: 'comedy',
                price: 10
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 10,
        name: 'Author XYZ'
        highest_price: 12
        books: [
            {
                id: 3,
                name: 'book3',
                category: 'comedy',
                price: 12
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What I got so far:

```
Author::with(['books' => function($query) {
    $query->where('category', 'comedy')
        ->where('created_at', '>=', $someFromDate)
        ->where('created_at', '<=', $someToDate);
}])
->has('books', '>', 0)
->get()
->dd();
```

But this just gives me all the authors that have books, it does not take into account the condition in the eager loading...

Is it even possible in 1 query?
Any help would be appreciated!

## SOLUTION

Thanks to the answers, I found out that what I need was a combination of `with()` and `whereHas()` (found answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29594039/5297218). Because the "where" conditions has to be in both methods, I used a [query scope](http://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes) on the Author model:

```
public function scopeWithAndWhereHas($query, $relation, $constraint){
  return $query->whereHas($relation, $constraint)
               ->with([$relation => $constraint]);
}
```

For the extra `highest_price` attribute I've used the `transform()`method on the [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections), in combination with `max()` method to get the highest price. This is the final result:

```
Author::withAndWhereHas('books', function($query) use ($category, $date){
    $query->where('category', $category)
        ->where('created_at', '>=', $date->get('start'))
        ->where('created_at', '<=', $date->get('end'))
        ->orderBy('price', 'desc');
})
->get()
->transform(function ($author){
    $author['highest_price'] = $author->books->max('price');
    return $author;
})
->sortByDesc('highest_price')
->values();
```

ps: this solution is 42x more performant that what I did before!

Answer (score 4):

There is two different results when using relation conditions:

1- Limiting RELATIONSHIP results based on a condition (which is what you are doing, but not what you want):

```
$authors = Author::with(['books' => function($query) {
    $query->whereNotNull('published');
}])->get();
```

Here you will have ALL authors regardless they have published books or not. Those with published books will have book info. All others won't.

2- Limiting PARENT results based on relationship condition (which is what you should use):

```
$authors = Author::whereHas('books', function($query) {
     $query->whereNotNull('published');
})->get();
```

Here you will have ONLY the authors having published books.

Note: If you want to eager load your Book model, you still have to use ->with('books')

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation! `whereHas()` was indeed what i was looking for!

Comment: Also, if I eager load Book model `->with('books')`will add all the author's books and not only those that matches the `whereHas()`criteria. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

That subquery on the `with()` will constrain what is loaded into the author's relationship to books, but will not constrain the author's that are returned. Have you tried `whereHas()` instead of `with()`? That will only return Author's who have books that fit that criteria. This is possible with one query, but it will depend a bit on what all you need. The addition of the field `highest_price` might be better regulated to a different relation.

```
Author::with('books', 'highest_price')->whereHas(['books' => function($query) use($someFromDate, $someToDate) {
$query->where('category', 'comedy')
    ->where('created_at', '>=', $someFromDate)
    ->where('created_at', '<=', $someToDate);
}])
->get()->sortByDesc('highest_price.highest_price');
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Awesome! `whereHas()` was exactly what I was looking for. Now I have the list of authors, but how can I add that extra attribute that holds the `highest_price` of the list of his/her books that match the `whereHas()` critera ?

Comment: I like the solution you posted @SebSob , and it will work for what you need. I would just be mindful that `transform()` will cause PHP to iterate over the collection, and that will slow you down if the collection gets too big (millions+, so not a big deal for now). There are a few ways to add mutated fields to what your query returns though, so if you get to a slowdown sometime down the line you can add it without needing to use transform.

Comment: Thanks @N Mahurin - Thanks for the tip! I know I could add a [mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators) `getHighestPriceAttribute()` to the Author model. But, it would have to match the given conditions (category and between dates); and I was not sure how to pass those to the mutator. Also, will a mutator query the DB for each record? Not sure if it's better for performance?

Comment: The problem with a mutator on a model like that is you couldn't sort by it until after you called `get()` to return the collection and the full data set. Which we want to avoid after it gets so big since PHP will not keep pace with the DB in terms of speed at a certain size. But by the time you have enough records to justify that, you'll also be using pagination and other tricks to keep the page load time down.

Comment: Ok. And sure, I will only be displaying max 50 authors, and per author max 100 books.

Answer (score 1):

From the result set in your question, below should give you what you need :

```
Author::whereNotNull('highest_price')
    ->has('books')
    ->with(['books' => function($query) use($startDate, $endDate){
        return $query->where('category', 'comedy')
            ->whereBetween('created_at', [$startDate, $endDate])
            ->orderBy('price', 'desc')
            ->select('id', 'name', 'category', 'price', 'author_id');
    }])
    ->orderBy('highest_price', 'desc')
    ->select('id', 'name', 'highest_price')
    ->get()
```

Explanation :

The easy way to get around these things is first structure the parent query builder, which is author in this case. So as per your requirement we checked for highest_price presence, filtered the authors which have at-least 1 book, ordered by highest_price desc and selected columns we need from authors table.

Now, looking into eager loading, we did the same, filtered the  created_at date range, order by price desc and selected columns required. I have added extra columns author_id which is foreign key deliberately so that is shows book results.

Comment: Thank you, but this won't work, because the Author has no column `highest_price`, it's something that has to be added on fly and which holds the highest price of the books of the author matching the criteria