# laravel eloquent complex select inside where statement

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

halo, i have data and want to display it like picture below

[image]

there are two models relationship, Person and Installment.

this is Person model:

```
class Person extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'person';
    public function angsuran()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Installment::class);
    }
}
```

this is Installment model:

```
class Installment extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'installment';
    public function person()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Person::class);
    }
}
```

and this is my controller to querying and display data

```
$data = Person::with('angsuran')
        ->whereHas('angsuran', function ($q) {
             $q->whereBetween('installment_date', [\DB::raw('CURDATE()'), \DB::raw('CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY')])
               ->where('installment_date', '=', function () use ($q) {
                  $q->select('installment_date')
                    ->where('status', 'UNPAID')
                    ->orderBy('installment_date', 'ASC')
                    ->first();
                });
            });
return $data->get();
```

it show error **unknow colum person.id in where clause**
please help. thanks.

Comment: $q should be inside the function($q) instead of use ($q)

Comment: I already did that bit it shown error like query doesn't know the table name

Comment: yes, you also need to specify a table, $q->select('installment_date').. but from where? you can use $q->from('table_name')->select(...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment said, you need to put `$q` as a parameter to the Closure.

When using subqueries, it's useful to tell the query builder which table it is supposed to query from.

I've rewritten your query. It should achieve what you're looking for. Also, changed the `CURDATE` to Carbon objects.

`today()` returns a datetime to today at 00:00:00 hours. If you need the hours, minutes and seconds, replace `today()` by `now()`.

```php
$data = Person::with('angsuran')
->whereHas('angsuran', function ($subquery1) {
    $subquery1->where('installment_date', function ($subquery2) {
        $subquery2->from('installment')
        ->select('created_at')
        ->where('status', 'UNPAID')
        ->whereBetween('installment_date', [today(), today()->addWeeks(1)])
        ->orderBy('installment_date')
        ->limit(1);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `with` and `whereHas` you will end up with two query even if you have `limit(1)` in your subQuery and the result will show all 4 installment related to the person model. also I don't think you can order on the subquery, it should be before the ->get

so here's i've rewritten your code

```
$callback = function($query) {
    $query->whereBetween('installment_date', [today(), today()->addDays(7)])
            ->where('status', 'UNPAID')
            ->orderBy('installment_date');
    };

$data = Person::whereHas('angsuran', $callback)->with(['angsuran' => $callback])->get();
```

or you can use query scope. please see this answer [Merge 'with' and 'whereHas' in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591931/merge-with-and-wherehas-in-laravel-5)