# Laravel eloquent where clause if relation is not null

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship, laravel-6.2

I have this query:

```
$answers = AnswerVersion::query()->with(['answer' => function($q) use ($project) {
    $q->where(['project_id' => $project->id]);
}]);
```

And I want to add modify it to only return AnswerVersion results that actually have an `answer` relation. Right now it only queries for the project_id match when the answer relation exists and otherwise ignores that query and returns the AnswerVersion regardless. Is there a way I can do that in the callback or essentially a `whereNotNull` on the relation? I can't flip the query as I need to come at it from the AnswerVersion relationship for a CSV report, so I understand that coming from Answer -> AnswerVersion where project_id is a match makes the most sense SQL-wise. That however would not work for this report which requires a row for each AnswerVersion with the Answer information included. The raw SQL query would look something like this:

```
SELECT
   * 
FROM
   answer_versions AS AV 
   INNER JOIN
      answers AS A 
      ON AV.answer_id = A.id 
WHERE
   A.project_id = 1;
```

Comment: use `whereHas` instead. if you want to bring the aswer relation take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591931/merge-with-and-wherehas-in-laravel-5

Answer (score 2):

The sql query which you have shown in your post will give you `answer_versions` that belongs to those `answer` where `project_id` is 1 and the query you have from query builder will fetch all `answer_versions` regardless their related answer belongs to project 1 or not.

But in result set you will have answers for some of `answer_versions` because you have applied filter in `with()` which just loads the related records.

In order to get the results same as provided sql query you will need a filter on main clause instead of applying filter in `with()`

```
$answers = AnswerVersion::query()->with('answer')
            ->whereHas('answer.project', function ($query) use ($project) {
                $query->where('project_id' ,$project->id);
           });
```